# Questions about ``$p$-canonical basis" for $\widehat{\mathfrak{sl}_n}$ module (wedge power of natural representation)

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras, quantum-groups, modular-representation-theory

Let $p$ be a prime number. Consider the natural representation of the affine Lie algebra $\widehat{\mathfrak{sl}_p}$, defined as follows.
$$A = \bigoplus_{i=1}^N \mathbb{C}a_i; \qquad \text{nat}_p = A \otimes \mathbb{C}[t, t^{-1}]$$

There's a natural action of $\widehat{\mathfrak{sl}_p}$ on $\bigwedge^n \text{nat}_p$ (here $\bigwedge$ denotes the wedge power). Let $\textbf{k}$ be an algebraically closed field with characteristic $p$, and $G = \text{SL}_n(\textbf{k})$.   [Chuang-Rouquier] categorify this action as follows; see pg 58 (beginning of Section 2) in [Williamson-Riche](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.08296) for a detailed exposition.

\begin{align*} K^0(\text{Rep}(G)) \simeq \bigoplus_{\lambda \in X^+} \mathbb{C}[\Delta(\lambda)] \end{align*}

In the above isomorphism, $\Delta(\lambda)$ denotes the Weyl module with highest weight $\lambda$, and $X^{+}$ denotes the set of all dominant weights. The Weyl modules give a basis in the Grothendieck group.

\begin{align*} \varphi: K^0(\text{Rep}(G)) &\rightarrow {\bigwedge}^{n} \text{nat}_p \\ \varphi([\Delta(\lambda)]) &= m_{\lambda_1} \wedge m_{\lambda_2 - 1} \wedge \cdots \wedge m_{\lambda_n-n+1} \end{align*}

**Definition:** Let the $p$-exotic canonical basis denote the classes of the simple modules in $\text{Rep}(G)$. As $p$ approaches infinity, then it's known that it stabilizes; we refer to that as the exotic canonical basis.

> How can we express the ``exotic canonical basis'' in terms of Lusztig's canonical basis for $\bigwedge^n \text{nat}_p$, viewed as a module for $U_q(\widehat{\mathfrak{sl}_p})$ (specialized at a suitable parameter)?

**Remark:** Let $p$ be a sufficiently large prime. Lusztig's conjecture describes the classes of the simple objects in the Grothendieck group, and involves affine Kazhdan-Lusztig polynomials; see Section 4 of Jantzen's expository article ``Character formulae from Weyl to the present" [here](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2528469).   This shows that the $p$-exotic canonical basis stabilizes as $p$ approaches infinity, and gives a method of computing the exotic canonical basis. However, the answer to the above question takes additional work.

Comment: It would help to explain your notation a bit further, starting with the notion of affine Lie algebra and the symbol $N$.

Comment: For the definition of affine Lie algebra, please see wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_Lie_algebra

Comment: P.S.  When you refer to page 58, which version of the preprint are you pointing to?  (The page numbering shifts a little.)

Comment: It's the beginning of Section 2; that should clarify any confusion. Thanks for the edits, Jim!

Comment: I'm pretty sure you mean the beginning of *Part* 2 (currently on p. 58), not of *Section* 2 (currently on p. 17).  Is the Chuang–Rouquier reference to [Derived equivalences for symmetric groups and $\mathfrak{sl}_2$-categorification](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2373155)?